# Uniform boundedness of canonical factors in Weierstrass product

Tags: complex-analysis

This question refers to Lemma 4.2 of Stein & Shakarchi Complex Analysis.

Let the $k$-th *canonical factor* be defined by $E_k(z) = (1-z)e^{z+ \frac {z^2} {2} +  \frac {z^3} {3} +...+  \frac {z^k} {k}}$, for $k\ge 1$.

**Lemma 4.2:** If $|z|\le \frac 1 2$, then $|1-E_k(z)| \le c|z|^{k+1}$ for some $c\ge 0$.

Below is the proof as it is in the book. My problem is seeing that $c$ can be chosen the same for all $k$. In fact, Stein & Shakarchi claim that it can be chosen $c=2e$.

> *Proof:*
>   $z\le \frac 1 2 \Rightarrow E_k(z)=e^{log(1-z)+z+ \frac {z^2} {2} +  \frac {z^3} {3} +...+  \frac {z^k} {k}} = e^w$, where $w=-\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac {z^n} n$.
>
> Again, because $z\le \frac 1 2$, it follows that $|w| \le |z|^{k+1} \sum \frac {|z|^{n-k-1}} n \le |z|^{k+1} \sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-j} \le 2|z|^{k+1}$.
>
> In particular we have $|w|\le 1$, and this implies that $|1-E_k(z)| \le |1-e^w|\le c'|w|\le c|z|^{k+1}$.

I completely agree with the proof if I am allowed to pick a different $c'$ for each $k$, but I don't see how I can pick one for all, let alone why $e$ does the job (and hence $2e$ for $c$). I supposed that I could get some light if I found out where is the maximum of $|1-e^w|$ for $w$ in the unit disk, but this is not so simple as it may appear at first sight (if I didn't have the $1$, then the maximum would be, of course, achieved at $w = 1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum of $\lvert 1-e^w\rvert$ on the closed unit disk is attained in $w = 1$. That is easily seen by

$$\begin{align}
\left\lvert e^w-1\right\rvert &= \left\lvert \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{w^m}{m!}\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\lvert w\rvert^m}{m!}\\
&= e^{\lvert w\rvert}-1,
\end{align}$$

with equality for $w \geqslant 0$. By the mean value theorem, we have

$$e^r-e^0 = e^{\xi}\cdot (r-0)$$

for some $\xi \in (0,r)$. With $r = \lvert w\rvert \leqslant 1$, we have $e^\xi < e^1$, and hence

$$\left\lvert e^w-1\right\rvert \leqslant e^{\lvert w\rvert} - 1 \leqslant e\cdot\lvert w\rvert$$

for $\lvert w\rvert \leqslant 1$. Since $e^w = E_k(z)$, and $\lvert w\rvert \leqslant 2\lvert z\rvert^{k+1}$, that gives us

$$\left\lvert E_k(z)-1\right\rvert = \left\lvert e^w-1\right\rvert \leqslant e\cdot \lvert w\rvert \leqslant 2e\cdot \lvert z\rvert^{k+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I made a separate question about whether one can generalize your method that you might be able to solve http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638142/how-do-i-maximize-t-ez-for-z-in-d-the-unit-disk.

Comment: Looking at it right now.